# Is there a limit on how high the Entry IDs can go?

Tags: channel-entries, entryid

I've been trying to import thousands upon thousands of entries into a few different channels.

Before I get too far into my current project, I just wanted to clarify that there is no limit as to how high the entry IDs can go in ExpressionEngine.

Answer (score 5):

Entry IDs are stored as an unsigned integer field in MySQL, meaning the maximum value is 4294967295

Comment: The caveat is, it is an auto_increment column. So, if you create and delete a lot of test entries again and again (import and delete), and cycle through this procedure enough times, and reach ~ 4 billion then -poof-

Answer (score 3):

More a general MySQL tip: if you need to test the import and re-import a couple of times, keep an eye on the auto_increment value for the entry_id column of exp_channel_titles. Either reset auto_increment after deleting a test import, or set the entry_id value as well on import.

Comment: Great tip @gdmac!